# How do we form an equation from the dynamic data we have like in Harrod-Domer model after having different parameters and variable.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Currently I am reading a book DIFFERENTIAL.
EQUATIONS,
BIFURCATIONS, AND
CHAOS IN ECONOMICS

in which I need to identify how does an equation form from the real-world problem data and how we decide which type of differential equation it will form for example-We now consider dynamics of price of a single commodity.
Suppose that the demand and supply functions for the commodity are.
Qd = ax- bxP, Qs=-a2+ b2P, ap b, > 0,
where Qd and Qs are respectively the demand and supply for price P
and a} and bj are parameters. The market is in equilibrium when the
demand equals supply

now in above problem i want to know how Qd and Qs forms an equation.

please try to answer even if you have no expertise in this area (the question is not exact, but the idea is to know how a differential equation forms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.